# JavaScript output issue

Tags: javascript, output

I am presently trying to get a program to output a table of amortization. The program used to work, as it was a previous assignment. However, on that particular assignment, I was only to return "result" as a paragraph with the details of the loan and a table. The variables were entered due to an alert box.

Now we are trying to get the input via text boxes, and I am trying to output the table and info into a . Problem is, I am getting no output, and I cannot for the life of me find what is going wrong. The real assignment is to have input checking, so this is frustrating to say the least, as I am simply trying to GET TO the assignment at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated......

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Christopher" />
        <script src="scripts.js"> </script>
        <!-- Date: 2014-03-06 -->
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h3>Inputs:</h3>
            </legend>
            Loan Amount: <input type="text" id="principal" placeholder="10000" />
            <p>
            Interest Rate: <input type="text" id="interest" placeholder="5.5" />
            <p>
            Terms: <select id="selector">
                <option value="12">12 months</option>
                <option value="24">24 months</option>
                <option value="36">36 months</option>
                <option value="48">48 months</option>
                <option value="60">60 months</option>               
            </select>   
            <p>
            <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Calculate" onclick="amort()" />       
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h3>Outputs:</h3>
            </legend>
            <div id="outputArea"> </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    /**
 * @author Christopher
 */
function amort(balance, interestRate, terms)
{
    var principal = document.getElementById("principal").value;
    var interestRate = document.getElementById("interest").value;
    var terms = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var monthlyRate = interestRate/12;
    var payment = balance * (monthlyRate/(1-Math.pow(
        1+monthlyRate, -terms)));
    var result = "Loan amount: $" + balance.toFixed(2) +  "<br />" + 
        "Interest rate: " + (interestRate*100).toFixed(2) +  "%<br />" +
        "Number of months: " + terms + "<br />" +
        "Monthly payment: $" + payment.toFixed(2) + "<br />" +
        "Total paid: $" + (payment * terms).toFixed(2) + "<br /><br />";

    result += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Month</th><th>Balance</th>" + 
        "<th>Interest</th><th>Principal</th>";

    // insert your code here
    i=1;
    var balance = principal.toFixed(2);
    var interestPaid = balance * monthlyRate;
    var principalPaid = (payment - interestPaid).toFixed(2);
    //var totalPayment = interestPaid + principal;

    while (i<=terms){
        result+= "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + balance + "</td><td>"
         + interestPaid.toFixed(2) +"</td><td>" + principalPaid + "</td></tr>";
         var interestPaid = balance * monthlyRate;
         var principalPaid = (payment - interestPaid).toFixed(2);
         var balance = balance - interestPaid;
         var balance = (balance - principalPaid).toFixed(2);



        i++;
    } 
    result += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: you dont pass any parameters to the function `amort()`

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is wrong in the console of your browser.

Remove your parameters, and be carefull `.toFixed` is a method for a `number` so you have to parse your value.

```
function amort()
{
    var principal =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
    var interestRate =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("interest").value);
    var terms = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var balance = principal.toFixed(2);
    var monthlyRate = interestRate/12;
    var payment = balance * (monthlyRate/(1-Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -terms)));


    var result = "Loan amount: $" + balance +  "<br />" + 
        "Interest rate: " + (interestRate*100).toFixed(2) +  "%<br />" +
        "Number of months: " + terms + "<br />" +
        "Monthly payment: $" + payment.toFixed(2) + "<br />" +
        "Total paid: $" + (payment * terms).toFixed(2) + "<br /><br />";

    result += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Month</th><th>Balance</th>";
    result +=    "<th>Interest</th><th>Principal</th>";

    // insert your code here
    i=1;

    var interestPaid = balance * monthlyRate;
    var principalPaid = (payment - interestPaid).toFixed(2);
    //var totalPayment = interestPaid + principal;

    while (i<=terms){
        result+= "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + balance + "</td><td>"
         + interestPaid.toFixed(2) +"</td><td>" + principalPaid + "</td></tr>";
         var interestPaid = balance * monthlyRate;
         var principalPaid = (payment - interestPaid).toFixed(2);
         var balance = balance - interestPaid;
         var balance = (balance - principalPaid).toFixed(2);

        i++;
    } 
    result += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = result;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q2cLE/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get output for debugging purposes, then you could try

```
WScript.Echo( terms );
WScript.Echo( payment );
```

and so on.